# How do you protect yourself against blackmail when you're about to leave a company?

Tags: unprofessional-behavior, employer, employees, toxic-culture

How do you protect yourself against blackmail when you're about to leave a company? I had a mental breakdown, because this guy has been harassing me and insulting me for 15 months and management didn't do anything about it. There's this director of my department who tries to do everything to make himself look good and pretend that the people he hires are competent when they're not. So I've had enough, and I am going to leave. However, this guy blackmailed me by saying that I might get fired if I am not good enough, and I was like the best developer they've had for a while it's just that he was too incompetent to see it. Now, I fear this guy might blackmail me and try to find some crappy excuses if he gets in trouble for it like "cultural differences" and "language barriers". How do I protect myself from him? Can I refuse to talk in a Google Meet after I give my 2 weeks notice?

Comment: I don't want you to go into too much detail, but what may he blackmail you about?

Comment: You can't decide to stop doing your job once you give your notice. If going onto Google Meet is a requirement of your job, then you have to continue doing it.

Comment: It’s not clear what you mean by blackmail. That’s normally when someone knows something embarrassing about you and threatens to make it public to get something out of you. Is it possible you mean badmouth?

Comment: Is that guy your team lead, manager, senior manager, or director ?  Does he determine your salary raise,  job performance or job security ? If not, then why do care what he says about your job performance during those 15 months ?

Comment: Are you worried he's going to fire you for quitting? Something else? It'd be easier to suggest how to protect yourself if you're clearer about what outcome(s) you're trying to protect yourself from.

Answer (score 6):

Hand in your notice. That's all you need to do.

I'm making an assumption that your reference to 'blackmail' is simply that you feel he might badmouth you within the company. If so, don't respond; you only have two weeks left anyway. If you don't hand in your notice, it will be a rough 'rest of your career' - so do what's right for you.

You can't really refuse to talk in a Google Meet, but you can refuse to rise to accusations. If you're accused of 'not being good enough', your response is 'I'm leaving anyway'.

Comment: Great answer, your response is your responsibility.  In this case, OP, if they say something negative during your 2 week notice period simply respond with "well I guess you are happy that I am leaving".

Answer (score 1):

In all likelihood you are dealing with a narcissist and there is no winning, only short-term survival. Anyone can fabricate a story and try to use it to blackmail you; narcissist will excel at it.

Two weeks notice is a professional courtesy typically reserved for situations where the employee has had a good working relationship with their employer and they've decided to pursue another opportunity, maybe for more money or maybe to simply pursue new skills and interest. Think about it this way: How many employers give two weeks notice when they fire someone. None. You need to fire your company.

It sounds like you do not have a good working relationship with your company because they have hired/installed an evil human being to oversee you. I would not give them two weeks notice. I wouldn't give them 5 minutes notice. On Sunday night I would draft a resignation memo to your boss and cc his management and the human resources department detailing the unacceptable work environment that has been created by said boss and simply state that you quit, effective immediately. Best case scenario is that the management above your boss will get the message that there is a problem and attempt to bring you back into a different department, or they are evil too, in which case, you really will be better off some place else.

Look at it this way: You think that by giving them two weeks notice, they will give your next employer a good recommendation of our skills and accomplishments. You are wrong. They were evil when you worked for them and they will continue to be evil after you leave. Just leave.